# stunnel TIMEOUTconnect on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: stunnel, ubuntu-15.10

We use stunnel extensively for LDAP proxying. We recently set up a Ubuntu 15.10 server to migrate some of the tunnels to and are unable to get it to work.

We've scraped through the logs, configs, docs, etc. and at our wits end on figuring it out. Right now, we're under the assumption that there's something with the distribution that's keeping it from working. However, we're simply grasping at straws.

We can successfully connect to the tunnel, but the tunnel does not successfully connect out, but instead errors with the following:

Error:

```
s_connect: s_poll_wait xx.xx.xx.xx:xxx: TIMEOUTconnect exceeded
Connection reset: 0 byte(s) sent to SSL, 0 byte(s) sent to socket
```

Config:

```
pid = /var/run/stunnel.pid
debug = debug
output = /var/log/stunnel.log
fips = no

[ourName]
accept = 3100
connect = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx
CAfile  = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
cert = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
client = no
```

Any thoughts about anything else we can try or what might be getting in the way?

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: also curious...